# Python- Count list of items in a text file

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I am struggling to write the code to get the count of list of items

```
keywords = ['bed', 'slot', 'display pane', 'graph', 'bedsides', 'multiviewer display', 'bed1']
```

In a text file containing the below sample text.

```
 Verify that the Respiration waveform size can be modified.                             
 Verify that changed Respiration waveform size is updated in Central Station.                               
 Verify that the Respiration Lead Selection settings are displayed as read-only for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station.                               
 Verify that the NBP Auto mode settings are displayed for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station.                                 
 Verify that the NBP cuff size settings are displayed as read-only for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station.                                
 Verify that the ECG lead analysis options displayed for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station include the following:                                
 Verify that the adjustment of the ECG Lead Analysis setting from Single-Lead and Multi-Lead is permitted for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station.                                 
 Verify that the ECG Detect Pace settings displayed for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station include the following:                             
 Verify that the adjustment of the ECG Detect Pace setting from PACE1    PACE2 and OFF is permitted for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station.                           
 Verify that the ECG Display Lead settings displayed for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station include the following:                                
 Verify that the adjustment of ECG Display Lead setting from I   II  III     V   aVR     aVL and aVF for the Telemetry Bed is permitted at the Central Station.             
 Verify that the SpO2 Waveform Size settings are displayed for the Telemetry Bed but it's read-only(grayed out).                                
 Verify that the Central Station shall display the NIBP auto mode setting as read only.                             
 Verify that the displayed NBP Stat mode settings are read-only for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station.                               
 Verify that a means to clear the NBP message is provided for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station.                             
 Verify that the message displayed for the Telemetry Bed in the Multiviewer  slot is cleared.                               
 Verify that the ECG Va Lead Selections displayed for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station include the following:                               
 Verify that the adjustment of the ECG Va Lead Selection setting from V1     V2  V3  V4  V5 and V6 is permitted for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station except for one of the Va lead which will be greyed out based on the Vb lead selected.              
 Verify that the ECG Vb Lead Selections displayed for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station include the following:                               
 Verify that the adjustment of the ECG Vb Lead Selection setting from V2     V3  V4  V5 and V6 is permitted for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station except for one of the Vb lead which will be greyed out based on the Va lead selected.                  
 Verify that the NBP Stat Mode setting is displayed as a read-only value of either ON or OFF for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station.                              
 Verify that the message displayed for the Telemetry Bed in the Multiviewer  slot is cleared.                               
 Verify that the adjustment of the SPO2 rate setting is permitted for the Telemetry Bed at the Central Station.
```

Note: I would also want to convert above text into lowercase before finding the count of list items.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `re.findall` (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.findall)

With `re`  you can ignore case, so you won't need to lowercase all your text before :)

Comment: I have tried using the re.findall . for every line of the text file I am running below code snippet. <br/> re.findall ('|'.join(Keywords),line,re.IGNORECASE)       <br/>  using which i am able to identify only the occurrences of key words bed, slot and graph. rest of the words in the list were not  identified. please help with the regex.